# Finding out the value of a boolean in a custom class

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, boolean

[image]I have a custom class script that is given below and I have attached an image of how it looks in the inspector. Suppose, I want to know if the 'has Bought' boolean of 'Apply some pressure' is true. How can I know it? Also, how do I set another bool equal to it? Code of the custom class script:

```
[System.Serializable]
public class Buyables
{
    public string name; // A string called as Name

    public int price; // An integer called as price

    public bool hasBought; // A bool called as has bought
}
```

Comment: _"I have attached an image of how it looks in the inspector"_ - no you haven't.

Comment: Can you show us the definition of `Money`?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen It's another script idk how it can be useful here.

Comment: @AnimeShinjas It might show us how the `Buyables` are related to it - are they organized into an array, a list, a dictionary?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen It's okay, it's solved now :] Also, that's for willing to help, I asked the same question in unity answers and no-one answered so yeah, thank u for that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to know if the 'has Bought' boolean of 'Apply some pressure' is
> true

Get the reference of your Money Class.

```
Money money;
```

Check boolean value with:

```
money.buyables[1].hasBought == true
```

> how do I set another bool equal to it?

```
anotherBoolVariable = money.buyables[1].hasBought;
```

Comment: @AnimeShinjas you're welcome ^^ remember to mark the answer as correct so other people can reach it fast